# Cannot POST using express and body-parser

Tags: node.js, post

Please can you help me out, for some reason I am not able to post and am getting a "cannot POST /api/create" and when inspecting the page a 404 error is shown.

Here is my index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mainRouter = require('./mainRouter.js');
var todoRoutes = require('./todoRoutes.js');

//tell express to use bodyParser for JSON and URL encoded form bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//mouting our routers
app.use('/', mainRouter);
app.use('/todo',todoRoutes);

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server running on port 3000");
```

And the corresponding todoRoutes.js file is where I require the post method:

```
var express = require('express');
var todoRoutes = express.Router();
var todoList = []; //to do list array


todoRoutes.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/todo/index.html');
});

todoRoutes.get('/create', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/todo/create.html');
});

todoRoutes.get('/api/list', function(req, res) {
res.json(todoList); //respond with JSON
});

todoRoutes.get('/api/get/:id',function(req, res){
res.json(todoList[req.params.id]); 
});

todoRoutes.post('/api/create', function(req, res){
console.log("Creating the following todo:", req.body.todo);
todoList.push(req.body.todo);
res.send({redirect: '/api/list'});
});
```

and here is the corresponding html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <title>Todo List: Create</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "/api/create" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="todo">Enter your new Todo:</label>
        <input type="text" id="todo" name="todo">
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </div>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

If I put a console.log("") in the POST function of the todoRoutes.js file it will not be displayed, indicating that the function does not even get executed.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to POST to /todo/api/create, based on your current route handling:

```
<form action = "/todo/api/create" method="post">
```